# Sox : merge two audio files with a pad

Tags: audio, merge, delay, sox, pad

I'm using the `sox` tool and I would like to **merge two audio files**, let's say `long.ogg` and `short.ogg` to output a file `output.ogg`.
This is very easy using `$ sox -m long.ogg short.ogg output.ogg`.

Thing is, I would like the `short.ogg` to be **played after n seconds** (while `long.ogg` should start right from the beginning). To do so, I've found the *pad* effect. But I don't understand the syntax to delay only the `short.ogg` input file, not the `long.ogg` one.

I found a (dirty) way of doing so (with n=6):

```
$ sox short.ogg delayed.ogg pad 6
$ sox -m long.ogg delayed.ogg output.ogg
```

I would like not to have to create an intermediate file. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to icyrock, I managed to find a solution. I'm using:

```
$ sox short.ogg -p pad 6 0 | sox - -m long.ogg output.ogg
```

For multi tracks (credits to Orlando):

```
$ sox starts-last.mp3 -p pad 2 0 | sox - -m starts-second.mp3 -p pad 2 0 | sox - -m starts-first.mp3 combined.mp3
```

Comment: how to this with multiple tracks? 3,4,5 tracks

Comment: For multiple tracks:

sox starts-last.mp3 -p pad 2 0 | sox - -m starts-second.mp3 -p pad 2 0 | sox - -m starts-first.mp3 combined.mp3

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to do something like:

```
sox short.ogg -p pad 0 6|sox - long.ogg output.ogg
```

`-p` option to sox is used for piping - basically, it tells sox to use stdout as the output. Using `-` as the input to the second sox is actually saying input is stdin (which happens to be the stdout of the previous sox, as we are piping with `|`). `pad 0 6` tells pad 0 seconds at the beginning and 6 seconds at the end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I actually had to add the mix option `-m` because without it, the whole sound was delayed. Please see my edit.

Comment: I did not read the question - what I wrote will play short.ogg, wait 6 seconds and then play long.ogg, writing the whole result to output.ogg. Anyway, glad you found the solution! I suggest adding it as an answer and officially choosing as the solution - for the others with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution benefiting from the use of double-quotes. It makes the command much more readable and very easy to extend:

```
sox −−combine sequence  "|sox input/odin.wav -p pad 0 1" "|sox input/dva.wav -p pad 0 1" "|sox input/tri.wav -p pad 0 1" output/test.wav
```

This would concatenate all three files, with a 1-second pause after each (odin, silence, dva, silence, tri, silence.)

Applied to the original post, we'd get:

```
sox −−combine sequence  "|sox long.ogg -p pad 0 6" "|sox short.ogg -p pad 0 1" newfile.ogg
```

(Tested OK on SoX 14.4.1 on Windows.)

I have hardly seen any SoX example using double-quotes, so I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Because I'm not allowed to comment yet, I would just like to say that I like Fabien's answer because it can also be used with the "NULL" soundfile: e.g.,

```
sox --combine concatenate "|sox -n -p synth 1 sine 300" "|sox -n -p synth 1 sine 400" useful.wav
```

Will write 1 second of a sine tone at 300 Hz followed by 1 second of a sine tone at 400 Hz and write it to the file "useful.wav".

```
sox -n -p synth 1 sine 300 | sox --combine concatenate - farts.wav synth 1 sine 400
```

Will only write 1 second of a sine wave at 400 Hz to the file "farts.wav". The file is missing the first sine wave at 300 Hz.

Answer (score 0):

Ran across delay command as well.

You could do the following:
sox.exe -m short.ogg long.ogg delay 6

This will merge the two files and short.ogg will start 6 seconds into long.ogg