# sox multiple pad while mixing

Tags: delay, sox, mixing

here is a solution to pad a track while mixing with another track.

[Sox : merge two audio files with a pad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587135/sox-merge-two-audio-files-with-a-pad)

```
$ sox short.ogg -p pad 6 0 | sox - -m long.ogg output.ogg
```

How to use this command mixing multiple tracks?

For example

audio1.wav (no pad)
audio2.wav (2s pad)
audio3.wav (2s pad)
audio4.wav (3s pad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pad 6 0` prepends 6 and appends 0 seconds of silence, so I assume you only want to prepend silence.

You can do this with a `while` loop, for example in `bash`:

```bash
cat <<EOF > infile
audio1.wav 0
audio2.wav 2
audio3.wav 2
audio4.wav 4
EOF

while read fname len; do
  sox $fname -p pad $len 0 | sox -m -p long.wav output.wav
done < infile
```

I would suggest keeping the files uncompressed until your done processing.

Be careful of clipping when mixing, one way to avoid it is to apply `-6dB` gain to both signals and normalize after, e.g.:

```
  sox $fname -p pad $len 0 gain -6 | sox -m -p "| sox long.wav -p gain -6" output.wav gain -n
```